# Lock wall image order profile page

Tags: facebook

Does anyone know if there's any way to lock the Facebook wall header images so that they work as a continuous ad?  (as in these examples - http://reface.me/hacks/facebook-profile-photo-hacks/).

Its for a business fan page.

Any advice gratefully received!

Cheers
Paul

Answer (score 0):

There's no mechanism for locking the photostream. All you can really do (after you've set up your ad) is to edit out unwanted images by using the small `X` in the top right corner of the offending image.